# Using incorrectly for in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying  to substitu "i" in the for loop but I am finding this problem:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 33)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\" Line 33\n    \t\t\tUpdateExpression=\"SET #inc[\"\"\"i\"\"\"].#sta = :incidences\",\n"
  ]
}
```

The function before writing the loop was working good but the problem is when I am introducing the for loop

Here is my code:

```
    incidences = record['dynamodb']['NewImage']['incidences']


    for i in incidences:
        response = table.update_item(
            Key={
              'order_id': record['dynamodb']['NewImage']['order_id']['S']
            },
            UpdateExpression="SET #inc["i"].#sta = :incidences",
            ExpressionAttributeNames={
            '#inc': 'incidences',
            '#sta': 'status'
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
              ':incidences': "OK",
            },
            )
```

Can someone help me with that?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your `error` msg or `traceback`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to substitute `i` with its value in `UpdateExpression` but you are not doing it correctly.

Try this:

```
UpdateExpression= f'SET #inc["{i}"].#sta = :incidences'
```

I am not sure what the format of the query is. If the `["i"]` or `[i]`, that is up to you to check and correct in case.

Check https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings for more info on string formatting.